# What are integer literal types? And how are they stored?

Tags: c, constants, signed, unsigned-integer

I have just started learning C and a question has bugged me for a while now. If I write

```
int i = -1;
unsigned int j = 2;
unsigned int k = -2;
```

What is the type of integer literal `-1` and `2` and `-2`, and how does it get converted to get stored in `signed int` and `unsigned int`?

What is meant by signed integer, is that the property of variable or integer literal too? Like `-2` is signed integer and `2` is unsigned integer?

Comment: In C literals are constants that have their value predefined. Literals can be of any of the basic data types like an integer constant, a floating constant, a character constant, or a string literal. And regarding signed and unsigned integer it specifies that how the most significant is to be intepreted. In your case all the three -1, 2 and -2 are of type integer. A question  regarding difference signed and unsigned integer was asked on stackoverflow. You can refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812022/what-is-a-difference-between-unsigned-int-and-signed-int-in-c

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS Detail: Is is odd that in C, _character constants_ are not of type `char`, but of type `int`.  "An integer character constant has type `int`" C11 §6.4.4.4 10

Comment: No one here has mentioned two's complement which is how all "integer" types are stored whether signed or unsigned.  (the bits are the same, only the interpretation is different)  see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: The expression `-1` is not a constant (literal). It's an expression consisting of a unary `-` operator applied to the constant `1`.

Comment: @ebyrob: Two's complement doesn't apply to unsigned types.  It's the most common representation for signed types, but not the only one.

Comment: @KeithThompson representation's other than two's complement are pretty rare: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276957/are-there-any-non-twos-complement-implementations-of-c  Also, the "difference" between signed and unsigned is two's complement, and that difference seems to be what the question is about.  It's also one of the first subjects that comes up in an intro to programming course when discussing basic integer types.

Comment: @ebyrob: Yes, representations other than two's complement are rare. But again, two's complement is used only for signed types. Unsigned types use a pure binary representation.

Comment: @KeithThompson See This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406570/what-happens-internally-when-i-run-this-code , it is asking same thing , please answer it , it is a doubt i have for somany days now.

Comment: @KeithThompson Also when you says "Two's complement is only used for signed type" , you mean when object(variable) is of signed type right..??

Answer (score 11):

First off, `-1` is not an integer constant. It's an expression consisting of a unary `-` operator applied to the constant `1`.

In C99 and C11, the type of a decimal integer constant is the first of `int`, `long int`, or `long long int` in which its value will fit. Similarly, an octal or hexadecimal literal has type `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, or `unsigned long long int`. The details are in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.4.4.1.

`-1` and `-2` are *constant expressions*.  The result of the unary `-` operator has the same type as the operand (even if that result causes an overflow, as `-INT_MIN` does in most implementations).

```
int i = -1;
```

The constant `1` and the expression `-1` are both of type `int`. The value is stored in the `int` object `i`; no conversion is necessary. (Strictly speaking, it's converted from `int` to `int`, but that doesn't matter.)

```
unsigned int j = 2;
```

`2` is of type `int`. It's converted from `int` to `unsigned int`.

```
unsigned int k = -2;
```

`-2` is of type `int`. It's converted from `int` to `unsigned int`. This time, because `-2` is outside the range of `unsigned int`, the conversion is non-trivial; the result is `UINT_MAX - 1`.

Some terminology:

A *constant* is what some other languages call a *literal*. It's a single token that represents a constant value. Examples are `1` and `0xff`.

A *constant expression* is an expression that's required to be evaluated at compile time. A constant is a constant expression; so is an expression whose operands are constants or constant expressions. Examples are `-1` and `2+2`.

Comment: You explain absolutely wonderfull , hats off , i have never seen so clear and wonderfull explaination. I have written a follow up question ,  , Question is here. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407568/why-do-we-have-unsigned-and-signed-int-type-in-c"

Comment: You said "-1 is not an integer constant. It's an expression consisting of a unary - operator applied to the constant 1." But " the type of a decimal integer constant is the first of int, long int, or long long int" , so if `-1` is not integer constant why would it have any type , because type are defined for integer constant.

Comment: Every expression has a type.

Comment: You said "In C99 and C11, the type of a decimal integer constant is the first of int, long int, or long long int in which its value will fit." . So , isn't it contradictory.?

Comment: @Stranger: No, why would it be?

Comment: decimal integer constant has following type , and you said -1 is not decimal integer constant.

Comment: I like the added correctness and aim of this answer over my [now deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41406084/2410359) one.

Comment: @user7359847 A few years later: There is no contradiction. `1` is a decimal integer constant of type `int`. It's also an expression. `-1` is not a decimal integer constant, but it is an expression, and it also has type `int`. Its type is not determined by the rules for decimal integer constants, but by the rules for unary the unary `-` operator. "The result of the unary **`-`** operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand. The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type."

Comment: great. you haven't mentioned the literal suffix and why octal or hexadecimal literal is different

Answer (score 1):

## In C99 and C11

If you want to specifies the type of your integer you can use an [integer constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant):

You can write integer with decimal, octal or hexa representation:

```
int decimal = 42; // nothing special
int octal = 052; // 0 in front of the number
int hexa = 0x2a; // 0x
int HEXA = 0X2A; // 0X
```

### Decimal representation:

By default, the type of -1, 0, 1, etc. is `int`, `long int` or `long long int`. The compiler must peak the type that can handle your value:

```
int a = 1; // 1 is a int
long int b = 1125899906842624; // 1125899906842624 is a long int
```

That only work for `signed` value, if you want `unsigned` value you need to add u or U:

```
unsigned int a = 1u;
unsigned long int b = 1125899906842624u;
```

If you want `long int` or `long long int` but not `int`, you can use l or L:

```
long int a = 1125899906842624l;
```

You can combine u and l:

```
unsigned long int a = 1125899906842624ul;
```

Finally, if you want only `long long int`, you can use ll or LL:

```
unsigned long long int a = 1125899906842624ll;
```

And again you can combine with u.

```
unsigned long long int a = 1125899906842624ull;
```

### Octal and Hexadecimal representation:

Without suffix, a integer will match with `int`, `long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int` and `unsigned long long int`.

```
int a = 0xFFFF;
long int b = -0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
unsigned long long int c = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

u doesn't differ from decimal representation. l or L and ll or LL add unsigned value type.

---

This is similar to [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal).

Answer (score 0):

> What is the type of integer literal -1 and 2 and -2, and how does it gets convert to get stored in signed int and unsigned int?

The C parser/compiler, as previously said by chux, "understands" your literal as a signed integer - always. They are then casted to fit in the variable you assign to, which can be of different type. Doing this, some bits can be lost or they can change their meaning (for example, assigning a negative value to an unsigned int). Some compiler could warn you about a "literal out of range", other compilers could silently accept (and truncate) your literals.

> What Do You Mean By Signed Integer, is that the property of variable or integer literal too , like -2 is signed integer and 2 is unsigned integer.?

It is a property of the variable. In reality, it is a "type" - written as a "two words" identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the compiler and the architecture of the machine. Given `8 bits = 1 byte`, the following table summarizes different Integer types with their required sizes for both (signed) `int` and `unsigned int` on 32 and 64-bit machines:

```
+------+------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------+ 
|Type  |char  |short int|int    |long int|long long int|int pointer|
+------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------+
|32-bit|8 bits|16 bits  |32 bits|32 bits |64 bits      |32 bits    |
+------+------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------+
|64-bit|8 bits|16 bits  |32 bits|64 bits |64 bits      |64 bits    | 
+------+------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

As you may know, the biggest difference between (signed) `int` and `unsigned int` is that in (signed) `int` the Most Significant Bit (MSB) is reserved for the sign of the Integer and hence:

- a (signed) `int` having n bits can have a value between `-(2^(n-1))` to `(2^(n-1))-1`
- an `unsigned int` having n bits can have a value between `0` to `(2^n)-1`

Now, we can calculate the range (possible values) of different (singed) `int` types as follows:

```
+------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
|Type  |char     |short int |int       |long int  |long long int|int pointer|
+------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
|32-bit|-(2^7) to|-(2^15) to|-(2^31) to|-(2^31) to|-(2^63) to   |-(2^31) to |
|      |+(2^7)-1 |+(2^15)-1 |+(2^31)-1 |+(2^31)-1 |+(2^63)-1    |+(2^31)-1  |
+------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
|64-bit|-(2^7) to|-(2^15) to|-(2^31) to|-(2^63) to|-(2^63) to   |-(2^63) to |
|      |+(2^7)-1 |+(2^15)-1 |+(2^31)-1 |+(2^63)-1 |+(2^63)-1    |+(2^63)-1  |
+------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

Furthermore, we can calculate the range (possible values) of different `unsigned int` types as follows:

```
+------+-------+----------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------+
|Type  |char   |short int|int     |long int|long long int|int pointer|
+------+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+
|32-bit|0 to   |0 to     |0 to    |0 to    |0 to         |0 to       |
|      |(2^8)-1|(2^16)-1 |(2^32)-1|(2^32)-1|(2^64)-1     |(2^32)-1   |
+------+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+
|64-bit|0 to   |0 to     |0 to    |0 to    |0 to         |0 to       |
|      |(2^8)-1|(2^16)-1 |(2^32)-1|(2^64)-1|(2^64)-1     |(2^64)-1   |
+------+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

Finally, to see how and why we store a `long long int` using 8 bytes (64 bits) on a 32-bit machine see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330374/long-long-implementation-in-32-bit-machine).

Comment: The range for signed ints is not correct. As the MSB is not simply a sign bit but two's complement is used on most machines, there is one more negative value than positive values. Also you need one bit too much. 
For signed int the range is -(2^(n-1)) .. 2^(n-1)-1. Your formula would result in -257..255 for char while it is -128..127

Comment: Good catch! I fixed the formula and updated the table as well!

Comment: I just saw that also the unsigned values are "off by 1". They go from 0 to (2^n) **-1**. Apart from that the size of your data types for 32 and 64 bit machines are not fixed. On 64 bit machines you could also get 64 bit integers.

Comment: Well, another one! I bet you can't find the third! Thanks for your help improving this answer! :-)

Comment: How does it answer the question though? Where does it say what the type of the integer constant `1` is? It is always of type `int` regardless of machine. It would also have been far more relevant to cite the table in 6.4.4 than this whole derailing of the topic.

Comment: @Lundin - This answer focuses on the storage and distinct properties of `signed` and `unsiged`, showing both `signed` and `unsiged` are having the same amount of storage. That being said, the `signed` and `unsigned` are two different data types. From the same document that you're citing - subsection 6.2.5, bullet 7: "The standard signed integer types and standard unsigned integer types are collectively called the standard integer types, .." which says `int` is an opaque data type for `signed` and `unsigned` types and I am pretty much sure that C compiler deals with them differently.

Comment: @MohammadHMofrad The part you cite is about grouping of types, where one group of types have the same integer conversion rank. Nowhere does it say that "int is an opaque data type for signed and unsigned", you are making this up. `int` is always equivalent to `signed int`, see 6.2.5/4. It is true that `signed int` and `unsigned int` are different types. **None of which has anything to do with the question** which is about what type an _integer constant_ ("literal") has. Which can be answered by reading/citing 6.4.4.

Comment: @Lundin I am not making something up here because the stuff I borrowed from the reference are quoted and you can find it in the 6.2.5 specification. Also, what I'm trying to say here is that the signed and unsigned types have same storage yet different conversion step. Of course, for a constant of type signed int compiler decays it to a smaller unsigned int while doing the conversion yet the range is smaller compare to the unsigned one which is also in my answer.

Comment: What. Is. The. Type. Of. An. **Integer literal**. This is the question. Not "how big is an integer", that's a different question. Nowhere in your "answer" is the term integer literal mentioned, nor is the correct formal term _integer constant_. Just read the answer by Keith Thompson which does answer the question.