# How are negative numbers stored in "hard" memory when they are encountered during compilation?

Tags: c++, memory, hardware, twos-complement

I am in the process of learning C/C++, so for some this might be a basic question but it is confusing to me.

Beautiful answers are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407568/why-do-we-have-unsigned-and-signed-int-type-in-c) related to how we interpret positive and negative numbers and how they look like in-memory (RAM memory) when the program is executing.

What I am thinking now is how are negative numbers stored in a compiled exec binary file; that is, when the program is not executing (not in a RAM memory). **In other words, how are negative numbers after compiling stored on hardware hard disk (so when the program is not executing).**

Will the compiler, when sees a negative number, for example `int number = -25`, first convert it to the 2's complement (`1110 0111`) and then store it in exec binary file (hard disk), or will it store it only as 25 with the highest bit set to 1 (`1001 1001`), and later when the execution of the program starts and when it sees that the most significant bit is 1, it will first convert it to the 2's complement (`1110 0111`), then load it into RAM (allocate memory, whatever) and start execution?

Comment: Note: It is only recently (C++20) that C++ finally admitted the supremacy of twos complement and incorporated it into the Standard as a guarantee. Before that you pretty much always got two's complement but without any guarantee.

Comment: Learning two very different languages in tandem is hard work.  Choose which language you're asking about.  In general, the answers will be different for the two languages, which means your question needs more focus.

Comment: Considering this is year 2023 going on 2024, you would expect at this stage that microprocessors know how to handle negative numbers without any runtime "conversion" that you are speaking of.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I started with C to learn basics (types, pointers, memory allocation etc), but now I am learning C++ to become more familiar with object oriented programming language and classes. I thought its the same for both of them. Hmm, an answer related to either of these two languages would mean a lot to me, and if possible for both, even better.

Comment: @MudjaAdjum [Look at compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/va3WGaK3v).  You don't see any calls in the assembly language window to do some type of conversion.

Comment: In general, do not tag a question on SO with both C and C++ unless you particularly like the idea of earning downvotes, or unless your question is about the interworking of C and C++ in some way.  Ask about whichever language you are currently working with (it sounds like that's C++), even if you think the answer might be the same in the other language.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay, but how will it be stored on a hard disk, that is in a binary execution file, in 2's complement or in the second more "intuitive" form (at least for me)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I edited it and left only C++ tag.

Comment: The negative numbers are stored just like positive numbers — in the native format for the machine for which the program is compiled.  In practice, that means a number like `-25` as a 4-byte integer is stored in two's complement format: 0xFFFFFFE7 in hex.  The byte order is, of course, the natural order for the machine (little-endian on many platforms, but big-endian on some).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So if I understood it correctly, the way in which the numbers are stored  after compiling on the hard disk (exec bit file) depends on the machine (its architecture) for which the compilation is performed. In most cases that is 2's complement. Is it correct?

Comment: In general, numbers (literals) are stored in a read-only section of the program or the executable section.  Doesn't matter if the number is negative or positive or zero.  Collections of constant numbers may be placed only in the data section of the program.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Okay, but I am wondering in which "format" are negative numbers stored. From other answers it looks like they are stored in 2's complement.

Comment: Whether negative numbers are stored as 1's complement or 2's complement depends on the processor.  The compiler will emit a processor instruction containing the value; the processor will fetch and interpret the instruction.  The processor's ALU (Arithmetic Logic Unit) will process the number.  To keep things efficient, the compiler uses the same number format as the processor.

Comment: Compile your program.  Look at a binary dump of the executable.  See what format your platform uses to store the number in the executable binary.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews So the compiler can store the negative number (but also anything else) however it wants (sign, 1's complement, 2's complement or something random) in binary exec file on hard disk, however in that case a conversion would be necessary before the negative number is sent to the processor because it works, for example, only with 2's complement represented negative numbers. Precisely because of this, the compiler immediately saves the data in the way that suits the processor so that these additional conversions are not needed and unnecessary spending processor time?

Comment: The short answer: it's up to the implementation (which collectively includes compiler, host machine, etc). It depends on the target architecture (how values are represented to the CPU), executable file format, and any design decisions by the implementer (e.g. to store in the "CPU native" format, in which case no "conversion" is needed - or not). Optimisation choices may eliminate the variable entirely, so it is not stored or retrieved at all. The C++ standard doesn't care, as long as a program exhibits required observable behaviour. The CPU just needs to receive a stream of valid instructions.

Comment: @Peter Nice answer. But generally (in most cases) it's always 2's complement when dealing with negative numbers? That way negative numbers are stored in the exec file, that way they are stored in the RAM memory and that way the processor consumes them?

Comment: @MudjaAdjum   Practically it may be.   But it doesn't have to be.  Although it is becoming increasingly common, not every CPU uses 2's complement for negative integral values.   C++20 mandating it for the language doesn't suddenly mean it is impossible to implement a compiler on a machine that doesn't use 2's complement, or that everyone using such a processor will buy new hardware.    As I said, it's up to the implementation.

Comment: For simplicity and efficiency, negative numbers are stored in the executable in the format of the native CPU.  This allows the executable to be loaded into memory, and the numbers loaded by the CPU *without any translations*.  Translations (like 2's complement to 1's complement) would slow the execution.  BTW, there are platforms where the executable is the mirror image of the executable instructions in memory.  This is primarily with embedded systems; load the image into memory, then run.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Just one question about "translation". "Translation" must be then done by my program? That is, if complier stored negative numbers in format different than the one CPU uses, then the compiler must also add into execution file (into my program) additional "code"/additional execution that will translate that "strange" format (strange to CPU) into CPU acceptable format?

Comment: @Peter Okay, but I have the same question as I posted to Thomas (comment above): How is that "translation" then done? Does the compiler, in case of storing a negative number in a different way than the CPU uses, have to add some additional code/instruction into execution file which will be used for conversion? So when it's time to access a given number, that set of instructions will first be executed on the given "bad" negative number format, and then the result (the correct format for the CPU) is passed to the CPU?

Comment: In general, there is no translation required because the compiler creates executables that match the numerical layout of the platform.  Same is true for Little Endian and Big Endian formats of multi-byte numbers.  If you have a 1's complement platform, the compiler will create an executable containing 1's complement numbers.  You don't run a 1's complement executable on a 2's complement platform.  Your program is clueless about how the compiler created the executable, as it should be.  "Speaking words of wisdom, let it be."

Comment: You only have a translation issue when your 2's complement platform is processing 1's complement numbers (for example, data from another platform); but that is another issue for another time.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks, so the conclusion is that it will be stored in memory (RAM or hard disk) in the same way as CPU works (there may be some very rare exceptions). Also, in 99% cases for negative numbers that's 2's complement?

Comment: It's fairer to say that the executable will contain values in a format supported by the architecture for which it is built. In a virtualised system, the program will run within a virtual machine or emulator. As far as the program is concerned, it is running on "platform X", but  the virtual machine actually executes on a different "platform Y".  The virtual machine translates the programs instruction stream to a stream of instructions for the underlying "platform Y", and gives results back (in suitable format) to the program.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specified by the language.  The compiler is free to do anything it wants so long as the behavior of the resulting program matches the behavior of the code you typed.

There are two common approaches that compilers take:

1. Store the number as two's complement (or whatever format the CPU works with) in the executable file.
2. Encode the number directly into immediate arguments to CPU instructions.

There's not really any reason to store numbers in a different format on disk and then do a conversion.  That would just waste CPU cycles unnecessarily.  When the OS's program loader loads an executable file, it copies various parts directly into various parts of memory.  If all of the program's numeric constants aren't already in the format that the CPU works with, then the program would have to do a conversion before using them.  That wastes time for no benefit.

Comment: Does the format of negative numbers can differ depending on whether they are in RAM memory or still non-executed in binary files on hard disk? For example, in RAM memory they are represented as 2's compliment while in exec file as sign representation? I suppose that it can, but that this should not be done because it makes no sense.

Comment: Also, can it be "represented" in RAM in a different way than the way the processor works? I suppose it can, but then it will need a conversion to CPU format before passing it to him (same as you described for exec bit files). All this requires unnecessary consumption of processor time, and that why negative numbers are placed in RAM in the same way as the processor does (same as in the case of ekec bit files)?

Comment: @MudjaAdjum: It would be possible to design a system where the format of numbers (positive or negative) depends on whether they're in RAM or in files on disk, but it's pretty safe to assume no system actually varies the format like that.  The system wants to be as efficient as possible, so it will arrange things so it just copies data from disk into RAM without having to do extra work.  Similarly, you could design a system so that data is represented differently in RAM than in the CPU registers, but no-one with an ounce of sense would design a system like that.

Comment: @MudjaAdjum: your continued pressing for information is verging on … annoying and/or disrespectful.  Be cautious.  The simple answer sometimes is **the** answer: under normal circumstances, the data is stored in the format most convenient for the CPU it is executed on.  Where there are exceptions, it is usually because the software is performing some stunt such as emulating a different CPU type.  You don't have to worry about such systems yet.  When (if) you do, you'll know what you're up to.

Comment: I don't do it often either, @MudjaAdjum — which is a measure of the extent to which I think you're in danger of pushing the boundaries.  I might have done it once or twice before in the last 15 years or so on SO.  Other people may have a different viewpoint.  As I said, be cautious.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As I said, have a nice day/night.

Comment: @MudjaAdjum `I am in the process of learning C/C++` already says that you're leaning something wrong. That's two languages which cannot be combined and in some ways they contradict each other. One is close-to-hardware language,iwhich sometimes used to program wiring of PLC, i.e. it programs physical _wiring_ there. Other is langauge is _intentionally_ torn away from hardware or physical representaiton. There are virtual machine implementations of C++, it isn't alien to an idea of garbage collector, etc. Representation of excutable depends on system used, not on language