# variable defined in the header by #define isn't set by the code

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I made a very simple code which calculates the values of a function:

```cpp
#define MIN 0.00001
#define MAX 1
#define MAXP 10000


 double func_log(double x)
{
    double r=RPWN;
printf(" MAXP = %e  \n",MAXP);
printf(" MIN = %e  \n",MIN);
printf(" MAX = %e  \n",MAX);

    double y;
    if (x>r || x==0) return(0.0);
    else {
        y = r+((r*r)/(2.*x)-x/2.)*log((1+r/x)/(r/x-1));  
    }
    return y;       

}
```

That fonction is in a file.c which is compiled with other source files. The problem is that `MAXP` cannot be set to its value. Here is what I get when I ask to print out the values of `MIN`, `MAXP`, and `MAXP`:

```cpp
 MAXP = 4.940656e-324  
 MIN = 1.000000e-05  
 MAX = 1.000000e+00
```

I really don't understand why I get `4.940656e-324`  for `MAXP`, I never had such issue. Also when I write `#define MAXP 10000.`, I then get `MAXP = 1.000000e+04`. I compile with gcc, does someone has any clue?

Comment: MAX and MAXP are integer constants being printed as doubles.  Happiness is not one of the options.  Add decimal points to the definitions.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Comment: @Lundin not necessarily a typo, the question is OK. For a beginner this behaviour may actually look strange

Comment: @MichaelWalz Fine, then close as duplicate to [What Are Integer Literal Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405578/what-are-integer-literal-type-and-how-they-are-strored).

Comment: @Lundin not close enough for me. And the OP will probably not understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in the value of `MAXP`, but in the format specifier `%e` that you are using to print it.

`MAXP` is not a variable, it is a macro. Hence, it has no type associated with it. The compiler figures out the type of `1000` from the context, which in case of `printf` means `int` (the default interpretation of `1000`). In a different context `1000` could be interpreted as a `float` or a `double`, e.g. `float f = MAXP;` An important thing to remember is that `MAXP` is textually replaced with `1000` in the body of your code.

If you want `MAXP` to be interpreted as a double by default, add `.0` at the end:

```
#define MAXP 10000.0
```

If you want it to remain an integer literal, use `%d` to print it

```
printf(" MAXP = %d  \n", MAXP);
```

or add an explicit cast:

```
printf(" MAXP = %e  \n", (double)MAXP);
```

Comment: In fact, you don't even need the `0` at the end (in case there is some possibility of it being mistaken by the programmer as a significant figure), you just need the decimal point or an exponent part.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `%e` prints float and double types, but your MAXP and MAX type integer.

You can use `%d` to print integers.